# How to display the views on the front page of Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

I am new to Drupal 6 modules and I am just learning the Views module right now. I have created a `News View` so far, edited the `Fields` and `Filters` on what I want to be displayed. My question is, how would I display my newly created views on the pages of my website like in the front page, should I add a condition on my `page.tpl.php` or should I configure on my `Blocks` ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Views, add a Display of type "Page".  Configure the "Page settings" and then you can use that page in menus or as the site front page.